# ¿Como crear un Tablero en react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, table, matriz

Me gustaría saber como puedo crear un tablero en react con un numero de filas y de columnas,
ya que me gustaría poder pedir el numero de filas y columnas y luego dibujar este tablero.

No se si tendría que tener dos arrays, uno para filas y otro para columnas, o algo asi

Me gustaría hacer algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea dos componentes uno llamado columns y otro llamado rows, como props manda el numero de columnas y filas, después tendrás que crear dos hook's del tipo array y en una función crear el arreglo del tamaño de las columnas y filas
[Mira esté ejemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-bassi-gy12j?)

Comment: Es ideal colocar el código de tu respuesta aqui mismo